# Buffer Overflow Not Overflowing Return Address

Tags: buffer, overflow

Below is the C code

```
#include <stdio.h>
void read_input()
{
    char input[512];
    int c = 0;
    while (read(0, input + c++,1) == 1);
}
int main ()
{
    read_input();
    printf("Done !\n");
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code, there should be a buffer overflow of the array 'input'. The file we give it will have over 600 characters in it, all 2's ( ex. 2222222...) (btw, ascii of 2 is 32). However, when executing the code with the file, no segmentation fault is thrown, meaning program counter register was unchanged. Below is the screenshot of the memory of input array in gdb, highlighted is the address of the ebp (program counter) register, and its clear that it was skipped when writing:

[LINK](http://tinypic.com/r/6i8c41/8)

The writing of the characters continues after the program counter, which is maybe why segmentation fault is not shown. Please explain why this is happening, and how to cause the program counter to overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tricky! Both `input[]` and `c` are in stack, with `c` following the  512 bytes of `input[]`. Before you read the 513th byte, `c=0x00000201` (513). But since `input[]` is over you are reading `0x32` (50) onto `c` that after reading is `c=0x00000232` (562): in fact this is little endian and the least significative byte comes first in memory (if this was a big endian architecture it was `c=0x32000201` - and it was going to segfault mostly for sure).

So you are actually jumping `562 - 513 = 49 bytes` ahead. Than there is the `++` and they are 50. In fact you have exactly 50 bytes not overwritten with 0x32 (again... `0x3232ab64` is little endian. If you display memory as bytes instead of dwords you will see `0x64` `0xab` `0x32` `0x32`).

So you are writing in not assigned stack area. It doesn't segfault because it's in the process legal space (up to the imposed limit), and is not overwriting any vital information.

Nice example of how things can go horribly wrong without exploding! Is this a real life example or an assignment?

Ah yes... for the second question, try declaring `c` before `input[]`, or `c` as static... in order not to overwrite it.